# Check whether two floats are in any of a given list of ranges

Tags: python, comparison

I have two floats `no_a` and `no_b` and a couple of ranges represented as two element lists holding the lower and upper border.

I want to check if the numbers are both in one of the following ranges: `[0, 0.33]`, `[0.33, 0.66]`, or `[0.66, 1.0]`.

How can I write that statement neatly in python code?

Comment: Is there anything you have tried yet and found not to be neat enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to get a `True` or `False` result, consider the following.

```
>>> a = 0.4
>>> b = 0.6
>>> 
>>> ranges = [[0,0.33], [0.33,0.66], [0.66,1.0]]
>>> 
>>> any(low <= a <= high and low <= b <= high for low, high in ranges)
True
```

If you have an arbitrary amount of numbers to check (not just `a` and `b`) you can generalize this to:

```
>>> numbers = [0.4, 0.6, 0.34]
>>> any(all(low <= x <= high for x in numbers) for low, high in ranges)
True
```

Comment: But what happens with the limits of the ranges?

Comment: @konstantin I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean whether the borders are included? You can finetune that with using `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
RANGES = [[0,0.33], [0.33,0.66], [0.66,1.0]]


def check(no_a, no_b):
    for rng in RANGES:
        if rng[0] < no_a < rng[1] and rng[0] < no_b < rng[1]:
            return True
    else:
        return False


print(check(.1, .2))
print(check(.1, .4))
```

Output is:

```
True
False
```

Or like this:

```
no_a, no_b = .1, .2
print(any(rng[0] < no_a < rng[1] and rng[0] < no_b < rng[1] for rng in RANGES))
no_a, no_b = .1, .4
print(any(rng[0] < no_a < rng[1] and rng[0] < no_b < rng[1] for rng in RANGES))
```

Output is:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html).

Put your `no_a` and `no_b` into an array and check if all events pass your statement.

---

Second Edit:
As pointed out, the built-in `all` function outperforms the numpy version for this small dataset, so the usage of numpy has been removed:

```
ranges = [[0,0.33], [0.33,0.66], [0.66,1.0]]

for i in range(len(ranges)):
    if all([ranges[i][0] < no_a < ranges[i][1], 
            ranges[i][0] < no_b < ranges[i][1]]):
        print('Both values are in the interval of %s' %ranges[i])
```

which will print out the range that both values fall into.

Comment: You are correct @timgeb. I was in a hurry before, so here you go.

Comment: Good  point. I timed it and indeed the built-in `all` is faster. I did a second edit and removed numpy.

Comment: Much better, but see my note about `any` on José Pedro Duarte's answer. (`all` and `any` have similar behaviour). However, I think the OP wants `any` rather than `all`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Numpy Using Broadcasting

```
import numpy as np

check = np.array([[0.4], [0.6]])
ranges = np.array([[0,0.33], [0.33,0.66], [0.66,1.0]])

((check >= ranges[:, 0]) & (check <= ranges[:, 1])).all(0).any()

True
```

---

#### Details

```
check >= ranges[:, 0]

#  0.00  0.33  0.66     <
[[ True  True False]  # 0.4
 [ True  True False]] # 0.6
```

---

```
check <= ranges[:, 1]

#  0.33  0.66  1.00      >     
[[False  True  True]   # 0.4
 [False  True  True]]  # 0.6
```

---

```
a = (check >= ranges[:, 0]) & (check <= ranges[:, 1])
a

#  0.00  0.33  0.66      <
#  0.33  0.66  1.00      >     
[[False  True False]   # 0.4
 [False  True False]]  # 0.6
```

In order for both values of `check` to be in one range pair, all of one column has to be `True`

```
a.all(0)

[False  True False]
```

Than as long as any one of these is `True`

```
a.all(0).any()

True
```

---

#### Numpy redux

However, we could have transformed the `check` and `ranges` to conduct one comparison operation.

```
b = [1, -1]
(check.T * b >= ranges * b).all(1).any()

True
```